# Db-Scheduler - distributing jobs across cluster better

Tags: db-scheduler

As a test - I have added 4 recurring tasks to a single scheduler and told them all to run at the same time. I have also given the scheduler 4 threads (.threads(4)). Now if I run this code on 10 separate nodes - backed by the same database of course, then I have observed that sometimes the 4 jobs can be running at the same time on the same node.. while all the other nodes are idle.

How can I get db-scheduler to always try to distribute the jobs across the cluster?  :(

The way I see it, is that I should aim for fewer schedulers, i.e have one scheduler instance manage many jobs (which I have done) while at the same time reducing its thread pool - that way it can only do a max number of jobs at once giving other nodes a chance to pick up the slack